# How can I speed up MongoDB deserialization for C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, reflection

When returning many results from a query, the code takes a really long time to convert the data into .net objects. These are basic objects, with a few strings as fields. I'm not sure but I think it's using reflection to create the instances which is slow. Is there way to speed this up?

Comment: Why is your question tagged with `asp-classic`?

Comment: That was an accident, not sure how to fix.

Comment: The docs clearly state that mapping is done through a "map" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 10gen driver doesn't use reflection on a per object basis.  It uses reflection once per type to generate a serializer using Reflection.Emit, so serialization or deserialization of the first object might be slow, but any objects afterward are fast (relatively).

Your question - is there any way to speed this up?

If your objects are simple (not nested documents, a few public fields, etc.), there probably isn't much you can do.  You could implement a custom serializer for the class to eke out a little performance, but I doubt it would be more than a few percent.

I haven't looked into it, and Robert Stam (who answered this question as well) would be the authority on it, but there may be some performance to be gained on multicore or multiprocessor systems by parallelizing deserialization in the driver.  I haven't looked at the driver code from that perspective yet, so it may be something Robert has already pursued.

On a general note, I think 30,000 objects in 10 seconds is pretty standard for just about any platform - SQL, Mongo, XML, etc that isn't storing objects as memory blobs directly (like you could using a language like C++).

EDIT:

It looks like the 10gen driver performs deserialization before it returns a cursor for you to enumerate.  So if your query returns 30,000 results, all 30,000 objects have to be deserialized before the driver makes a cursor available for enumeration.  I haven't looked at the jmongo driver, but I expect that it does the opposite, and defers deserialization until after an object is enumerated in the cursor.

The net result is that while both probably take the same amount of total time to enumerate and deserialize 30,000 objects, deserialization in the jmongo driver is spread across the entire enumeration, where in the c# driver it is frontloaded.

The difference is subtle, but likely to explain what you are seeing.

The bad news is the "fix" is a driver change.  One thing you could do is break your query up in chunks, querying for 10 or 100 objects at a time.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know if it was normal. Kind of disappointed it's so slow, doesn't that defeat the point? If I didn't type it and handled it as BSONDocument would it be faster?

Comment: I guess I would ask - slow as compared to what?  My experience so far is that MongoDB stacks up pretty well on query performance.  Without knowing more about you specific application I'm not sure I can offer more help.  To your question, you might be able to get some marginal improvement by working directly with a BSONDocument, but again, it really depends on the specifics of your application.

Comment: I mean, Mongo finishes the query instantly but when turning it into .net objects it takes 10 or so seconds. When I run the same query on a tool like jmongo it gives me the results immediately, so I was hoping there was some problem I was missing.

Comment: I just ran a test on my machine and was able to read 30000 documents in 0.53 seconds if they were deserialized to my test class or 0.38 seconds if they were deserialized to BsonDocument. My class had an Id of type ObjectId, two Int32 fields and 5 String fields of modest length (20-40 characters). I would like to help you find out why it is taking 10 seconds for you, because it is so much faster for me.

Comment: @RobertStam Here is my class, it's simpler than your test: http://pastebin.com/pVufS7y5  

Joe, that's the same conclusion I came to

Comment: And as mentioned, it's the enumeration that takes a long time, calling a ToList or a foreach. The FindAll() step takes < 200ms.

Comment: How much data in the HashSet?

Comment: Maybe 10-20 entries. I've more or less figured it out though, I was cheating and trying to do all the querying in-memory with C# and SelectMany and trimming it down to 60 results. I need to handle everything including the pagination in Mongo using map reduce. I profiled it and the fact is sending so much data takes that much time.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you are measuring. When the C# driver gets back a batch of documents from the server it deserializes them all at once, so there might be a lag on the first document but then the rest of the documents are really fast. What really matters is the total throughput in terms of documents per second and whether it is fast enough to saturate the network link, which it should be.

While there are hardcoded serializers for many of the standard .NET classes, serialization of POCOs is typically handled through class maps. Reflection is used to build the class maps, but reflection is no longer needed while doing the serialization/deserialization.

You could speed up serialization/deserialization a little bit by writing your own handcoded serializers for your classes (or by making your classes implement IBsonSerializable), but since the bottleneck is probably the network anyway it probably isn't worth it.

Comment: When I retrieve 30,000 objects, it takes around 10 seconds. It's not an advanced query, it just gets all the documents in a collection. Does that performance sound right to you? I'm currently using a memory cache to get around this but I'm wondering if there is another problem.

Comment: Can you show me your class declaration and a sample document? I'd like to try and reproduce your results.

Comment: @SwearWord: It's impossible to say how long "30,000 objects" should take to load.  If the records are simply a single int field it ought to be pretty quick.  However, if the records are megabytes in size each, then it will be pretty slow as your network connection plays a huge part in this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am using:

1. Read only needed fields
2. Cache objects which is often needed but rarely changed in memory
3. When I need to read many objects by rule (e.g. products by filter criteria) I store all products in single filter object and read all of them at once. Drawback is recalculate this cache when something changed.